# DocuSign - SignHereTab appears multiple times

Tags: docusignapi

Below is the Json Envelope Definition (with 2 documents and 1 recepient) that I'm `POST`ing at `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes`  and my expectation is that `SignHereTabs` should be displayed once on each document. But when viewing the document on [Docusign](https://demo.docusign.net/Signing/startinsession.aspx?t=9de21a85-9d11-4062-825f-b9b7e8d4b7c7), It is displaying `SignHereTabs` twice on each document as below. Please help me correct my JsonRequest object to display only once at each occurrence of `"anchorString": "!@&"`

[image: View]

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": FileBytes,
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "NameOfFile1111.pdf"
    },
    {
      "documentBase64": FileBytes,
      "documentId": "2",
      "name": "NameOfFile2222.pdf"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Test DS Email SUbject",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1234",
        "email": "joltoher@sezet.com",
        "name": "Client11 Client11",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "!@&",
              "documentId": "1",
              "recipientId": "1"
            },
            {
              "anchorString": "!@&",
              "documentId": "2",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent",
  "eventNotification": {
    "url": MyEndPoint,
    "envelopeEvents": [
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed",
        "includeDocuments": "true"
      },
      {
        "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined",
        "includeDocuments": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [Anchor Tagging](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs) you only need to set one `signHereTab`. DocuSign will find all the instances of the string `!@&` and place a tab there.

Change your **tabs** property as follows. I have removed the duplicate signHereTab. Also **documentId** is not required when you specify **anchorString** . Similarly recipientId can also be removed as `tabs` are already a child of recipient. The recipientId will be inherited from the parent.

```
"tabs": {
      "signHereTabs": [
        {
          "anchorString": "!@&"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Perfect (Y). Thanks